# Groovy method interception on all subtypes

Tags: java, groovy, metaprogramming, metaclass

I want to intercept all method calls for Script and any of its subtypes using MetaClasses preferably from Java but if needed I can do it from Groovy. I basically want to do something like this:

```
MetaClassImpl meta = new MetaClassImpl(Script.class) {
    @Override
    public final Object invokeMethod(Object obj, String method, Object[] args) {
        if(method.equals("evaluate")) {
            System.out.println("intercepted");
            return run(shell, (String) args[0], "Evaluate");
        } else {
            return super.invokeMethod(obj, method, args);
        }
    }
};
```

The above works fine if I apply it to every instance of Script that I create but I'd like to apply it to the Script class and have it apply to all of its subtypes. Is there any way of doing this?

EDIT: What I'm attempting to do is replace evaluate with another method for all instances of Script and its subtypes. Either that or get evaluate to respect the ImportCustomizer set on the groovy shell the script is running inside of.

Comment: Sounds like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Why are you trying to achieve this behavior? There may be better, easier ways to achieve it than what you think is needed. Can you edit the `Script` class? Please elaborate on the situation.

Comment: @VinceEmigh I edited the original question. This is what I'm trying to do: What I'm attempting to do is replace evaluate with another method for all instances of Script and its subtypes. Either that or get evaluate to respect the ImportCustomizer set on the groovy shell the script is running inside of.